# passwordless pkexec to unprivileged user

Tags: passwords, fedora, sudo, authentication, policykit

For several reasons I want to run my browser as a different system user on my fedora box.

For now I created a separate system user named `sandbox` and created a custom `~/.local/share/applications/chrome-sandboxed.desktop` file for Google Chrome with my user:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
Categories=Network;WebBrowser;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/unknown;x-scheme-handler/about;text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml_xml;image/webp;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;
Name=Google Chrome (sandboxed)
Exec=sh -c "xhost +SI:localuser:sandbox && pkexec --user sandbox env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U && true"
Icon=google-chrome
Actions=new-window;new-private-window;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=sh -c "xhost +SI:localuser:sandbox && pkexec --user sandbox env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable && true"

[Desktop Action new-private-window]
Name=New Incognito Window
Exec=sh -c "xhost +SI:localuser:sandbox && pkexec --user sandbox env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito && true"
```

After some struggle and research I found that [I need to allow the `sandbox` user to open windows in my session with `xhost +SI:localuser:sandbox`](https://askubuntu.com/a/981508/138369) and that [the `pkexec` command had to be enclosed in a separate `sh -c ""` command that ends with `&& true`](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1749668#post1749668) since it doesn't work in Gnome otherwise.
I even got this [set as my default browser by running `xdg-settings set default-web-browser chrome-sandboxed.desktop`](https://askubuntu.com/a/777222/138369), since it didn't appear in the GUI tool for choosing default applications before.

Now the only thing left that's bothering me is that I have to enter my password every time I click on a link in another application (i.e. Thunderbird) to authenticate against `pkexec` and run the program as another user (even though it will then realize there is already a process running and open the link in a new tab of the existing window - but I guess that logic is implemented in the application itself and can therefore only engage after the authentication has happened and the process is started).

Since I don't care about my user being able to access the `sandbox` user's stuff (it's the other way around that I want to prevent), I'd like to do this passwordless. I'm not sure about how to achieve this, though.

I read that it can be done by creating a `policykit` ACL. But since I don't want to [*generally* disable the password prompt](https://unlockforus.com/bypass-pkexec-password-prompt-admin-accounts/) and I have no clue about the custom "application's" name, which [seems to be relevant for fine tuned configuration](https://askubuntu.com/a/388660/138369) (if I understood the syntax in the answer correctly) I don't know how to disable the password prompt just for this application (and maybe further ones in the future).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Sorry, the tag `sudo` is probably confusing but I'd need 300 reputation  (which I do not have) to create the new tag `pkexec`.

---

**EDIT**

Got it working with the hints from [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686)'s [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1522674/207523).

First, (if there isn't already one) create a custom `policykit` policy file to configure an `action id` for the desired program - in my case `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/com.google.chrome.sandboxed.policy` (note that in this default policy `auth_admin` is  still required):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
                       "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
    <vendor>Google</vendor>
    <vendor_url>https://www.google.com</vendor_url>
    <icon_name>google-chrome</icon_name>
    <action id="com.google.chrome.sandboxed">
        <description>Run Google Chrome as another user</description>
        <message>Authentication is required to run Google Chrome as another user</message>
        <defaults>
            <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
            <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
            <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
        </defaults>
        <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable</annotate>
        <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
    </action>
</policyconfig>
```

Then, create a custom rule to allow passwordless execution of the action with the configured `action id` (`com.google.chrome.sandboxed` here) for your user only - in my case `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/10-passwordless_chrome-sandboxed_from_myuser.pkla`:

```
[No pkexec password prompt for myuser when running chrome-sandboxed]
Identity=unix-user:myuser
Action=com.google.chrome.sandboxed
ResultActive=yes
```

Afterwards, remove all occurrences of `env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` from your `.desktop` file, otherwise `pkexec` tries to execute `env` as the other user instead `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable`. As [user1686](https://superuser.com/users/1686) pointed out, the required environment variables are automatically inherited to the child process, so it's no longer needed anyway.

You might need to `systemctl reload polkit.service` or `systemctl restart polkit.service`, but I'm not sure about that since I thought that was the reason why it wasn't working for me at first - although I just forgot to change my `.desktop` file.

It works just as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how GParted handles it:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
                       "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
<policyconfig>
    <vendor>The GParted Project</vendor>
    <vendor_url>https://gparted.org</vendor_url>
    <icon_name>gparted</icon_name>
    <action id="org.gnome.gparted">
        <description>Run GParted as root</description>
        <message>Authentication is required to run the GParted Partition Editor as root</message>
        <defaults>
            <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
            <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
            <allow_active>auth_admin</allow_active>
        </defaults>
        <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/bin/gparted</annotate>
        <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">true</annotate>
    </action>
</policyconfig>
```

Note the two `<annotate/>` tags.

When this policy is installed, a simple `pkexec /usr/bin/gparted` is automatically assigned a different policykit "action ID" (so you can define different defaults, as well match it in custom rules). You also do not need to manually pass $DISPLAY – pkexec will copy all necessary variables automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try it ASAP and mark answer as accepted when I got it working.

Comment: Updated the question with the complete configuration and accepted your answer! Thanks again.

Comment: It just occurred to me that mouseover tooltips (like the text `A list of all 175 Stack Exchange sites` when you hover over the Stack Exchange icon at the very right of the top menu) are displayed as black boxes. I guess they are somehow created as a separated display element that lacks either the `$DISPLAY` variable or isn't allowed to "write" (?) to the display/session.

Not too severe, but if you've got another hint, I'd be happy to know.

Comment: I just realized that sound does not work. I guess that's a similar problem to the missing `xhost` permissions. But adding the user to the `audio` or `pulse` groups does not work. Any clue on what to do? Do I need to run `pulse` in the [**very** disencouraged](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/WhatIsWrongWithSystemWide/) [`SystemWide`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/SystemWide/) mode?

Comment: It's slightly less discouraged now that PA uses memfd internally. Aside from it, you could probably use PA's network audio support -- enable inbound connections via paprefs; firewall it to be only accessible to localhost; copy ~/.config/pulse/cookie to the target user; specify $PULSE_SERVER.